# cross product not associative, outer product associative

Tags: linear-algebra, clifford-algebras

The cross product is not associative. If $i=(1,0,0)$, $j=(0,1,0)$ and
$k=(0,0,1)$, then 
\begin{eqnarray}
 i \times (i \times j) = i \times k = -j \\
 (i \times i) \times j = 0
\end{eqnarray}

However in Geometric Algebra, if $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0)$ and
$e_3=(0,0,1)$ then 
\begin{eqnarray}
  e_1 \wedge (e_1 \wedge e_2) = (e_1 \wedge e_1 ) \wedge e_2 = 0
\end{eqnarray}

According to D. Hestenes, New Foundations for Classical Mechanics
(equation 3.13)
\begin{eqnarray}
   a \times b = -i a \wedge b  \quad, i=\sqrt{-1} 
\end{eqnarray}

So, where is the flaw here? Except for a complex scalar both definitions in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are the same. But.....one is associative and the other is not?

Thanks.

Comment: @AnyAD : I am not sure I understand your question. The outer product is associative. That is proved already in Geometric Algebra (it comes directly from the definition $A \wedge B=AB-A \cdot B$ where $AB$ is associative from the axiomatic definition of geometric product. The inner product $A.B$ is associative as well.) The subtraction will not change associativity.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $a,b$ (for example do they need to be linearly independent)?

Comment: No restrictions.

Comment: Your subscripts of $e_i$'s  have changed again. I don't have the book you mention so this makes it more difficult.

Comment: https://books.google.com.co/books?id=-mzyCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=%22while+spinors+are+usually+interpreted%22&source=bl&ots=X7lUX7jsQs&sig=TiGwjDYiY7W44PdevlL86rVaiD4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2_Ovx76nbAhUD0FMKHZgeBOEQ6AEwAHoECAEQKg#v=onepage&q=%22while%20spinors%20are%20usually%20interpreted%22&f=false

Comment: Page 60 on this link (I hope the link works):  https://books.google.com.co/books?id=-mzyCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=%22while+spinors+are+usually+interpreted%22&source=bl&ots=X7lUX7jsQs&sig=TiGwjDYiY7W44PdevlL86rVaiD4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2_Ovx76nbAhUD0FMKHZgeBOEQ6AEwAHoECAEQKg#v=onepage&q=%22while%20spinors%20are%20usually%20interpreted%22&f=false

Comment: So, one "product" is associative, and another "product" is non-associative....

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown I think they believe that the associativity of one implies the associativity of the other

Comment: @AnyAD That clearly isn't the case. Also the OP's comment "subtraction will not change associativity" is a blatant *non sequitur*.

Comment: $i$ is not a complex scalar. It is a real trivector. And the inner product is not associative. (Also, beware that geometric products are evaluated after wedges and dots: $i a\wedge b=i(a\wedge b)\neq(ia)\wedge b$.)

Answer (score 7):

The repeated wedge product $a \wedge (b \wedge c)$ has nothing to do with the repeated cross product $a \times (b \times c)$. Instead it corresponds (via the duality between trivectors and scalars in three-dimensional geometric algebra) to the scalar triple product $a \cdot (b \times c)$.

Comment: There is $a \cdot (b \wedge c)$ which is a scalar. The triple product $a \times (b \times c)$ is more like a pseudo-scalar. I would say that the first is more like $a \cdot (b \wedge c)$, right?

Comment: Still.....being $a \times b=-I a \wedge b$ seems natural to think that there ought to be associativity. It is non-clear where exactly this associativity is broken. Recall that $I$ is the pseudoscalar.

Comment: Sorry, but now I don't understand what you mean. I prefer the “contraction” notation $a \lrcorner (b \wedge c)$ to $a \cdot (b \wedge c)$, but either way it's not a scalar but a vector, namely $(a \cdot b) c - (a \cdot c) b$, which is plus or minus $a \times (b \times c)$ (I can never remember which). And I also don't see why you think that multiplication by $I$ is harmless to associativity; indeed $Ia \wedge b$ must be read (and should be written) as $I (a \wedge b)$, since $(Ia) \wedge b$ wouldn't even be a vector but a trivector.

Answer (score 4):

The basic point is that a difference of associative bilinear products will still be bilinear but need not be associative at all. Still, it's instructive to get an explicit expression for the associator of the cross product.

Let $I := e_1 e_2 e_3$, so that
$$
 \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}^3, \quad a \times b = -I(ab - a \cdot b) = -\frac{1}{2}I(ab-ba).
$$
Then for any $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^3$,
\begin{align}
 (a \times b) \times c &= -\frac{1}{2}I((a \times b)c - c(a \times b))\\ &= -\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(-\frac{1}{2}I(ab-ba)\right)c - c \left(-\frac{1}{2}I(ab-ba)\right) \right)\\ &= -\frac{1}{4}(abc-bac-cab+cba),
\end{align}
whilst
\begin{align}
 a \times (b \times c) &= -\frac{1}{2}I(a(b \times c) - (b \times c)a)\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}I\left(a\left(-\frac{1}{2}I(bc-cb)\right) - \left(-\frac{1}{2}I(bc-cb)\right)a\right)\\
&= -\frac{1}{4}(abc-acb-bca+cba),
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align*}
 (a \times b) \times c - a \times (b \times c) &= -\frac{1}{4}(abc-bac-cab+cba) + \frac{1}{4}(abc-acb-bca+cba)\\ &=\frac{1}{4}(bac+cab-acb-bca)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(b(a \wedge c)-(a \wedge c)b)\\
&= b \wedge (a \wedge c)\\
&= -I(b \wedge (-I(a \wedge c)))\\
&= -b \times (a \times c),
\end{align*}
so that $(a \times b) \times c = a \times (b \times c)$ if and only if $b \times (a \times c) = 0$.

Anyhow, for example, $e_1 \times (e_1 \times e_2) = e_1 \times e_3 = -e_2 \neq 0$, so that $(e_1 \times e_1) \times e_2 \neq e_1 \times (e_1 \times e_2)$; more explicitly,
\begin{align*}
 (e_1 \times e_1) \times e_2 = -\frac{1}{2}I(e_1e_1-e_1e_1) \times e_2 = 0 \times e_2 = 0,
\end{align*}
where, of course, $e_1 \times e_1 = -\frac{1}{2}I(e_1 \wedge e_1) = 0$, whilst
\begin{align*}
 e_1 \times (e_1 \times e_2) &= -\tfrac{1}{2}I(e_1(-\tfrac{1}{2}I(e_1e_2-e_2e_1)) - (-\tfrac{1}{2}I(e_1e_2-e_2e_1))e_1)\\
&= -\frac{1}{4}(e_1e_1e_2-e_1e_2e_1-e_1e_2e_1+e_2e_1e_1)\\
&= -e_1^2e_2\\
&= -e_2 \neq 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Dear Branimir:  I appreciate your insights. It seems that your same reasoning to show that $\times$ is not associative works to show that $\wedge$ is not associative. Right?

Comment: The wedge product **is** associative.
We have $xyz-zyx = xyz-zyx-x(yz+zy)+(yz+zy)x = yzx-xzy = zxy-yxz$,
which works because $yz+zy$ is a scalar and commutes with $x$.
So $x\wedge(y\wedge z)=x\wedge\frac{yz-zy}{2}=\frac{xyz-xzy\ +\ yzx-zyx}{4}=\frac{xyz-zyx}{2}=\frac{xyz-yxz\ +\ zxy-zyx}{4}=\frac{xy-yx}{2}\wedge z=(x\wedge y)\wedge z$.
The symmetry is broken in the cross product.